# Send email codeigniter function returns "Recipient address rejected: Domain not found" instead of false

Tags: email, codeigniter, error-handling

I'm using codeigniter. I test to send an email to a wrong inexistant address like t@t.com.

My code is just a method of the controleur like that :

```
function test() {
    $this->email->from('mymail@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to(htmlentities("t@t.com"));
    $this->email->subject('test');
    $this->email->message("Just a test !");     

    $r = $this->email->send();      
    if (!$r)
        echo "not sent, wrong email";
    else
        echo "sent";
}
```

Basically, the send() function returns true or false. But it doesn't work ! The error message I got is as following :

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.1.2 <t@t.com>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found

    Filename: libraries/Email.php

    Line Number: 1540

not sent, wrong email
```

I have the message, so send() function replies false but I also have the error message, which I don't want !

It's a blocking point. Anyone has an idea why send() function doesn't return the true or false reply ?

thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick and dirty hack to get rid of the error is to prepend the mail function with '@':

```
$r = @$this->email->send();
```

Comment: prepending '@' in front of a function call disables any errors that might be shown. It's considered bad practice because it can hide important errors + it's slow from a performance point of view

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will just use it for my local development and will not user it in preprod and prod environment.

Comment: I tested it on my preprod (without the @) and the answer of the send() function is always true, even if the recipient mail is unexistent. Is there a way to know that the email is not valid ?

Comment: with smtp you don't get an error message when the email address doesn't exists. if the email has a valid syntax xxx@xxx.xxx and the code manages to push the mail through the socket without errors then it is considered successful. the sending code is only responsible for sending the message to the smtp server and thats it.

Comment: if you want to check for the status of the email after it has been sent to the smtp server you need to create a script that connects to the imap or pop3 server related to the account through which you have send the email (ex: noreply@email.com) and check for failure delivery notices

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the answers. I will check all these informations.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and it works as it should, I get: **not sent, wrong email.**

What version of CI are you using? make sure it's the last one.

Just in case, check the **Email.php** library under **system/libraries** in your CI folder

```
protected function _send_with_mail()
{
    if ($this->_safe_mode == TRUE)
    {
        if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // most documentation of sendmail using the "-f" flag lacks a space after it, however
        // we've encountered servers that seem to require it to be in place.

        if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str, "-f ".$this->clean_email($this->_headers['From'])))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Check that the function **_send_with_mail()** inside looks exactly like the one above

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked this function and it's exactly the same. I use the CI 2.0.3, so not the last one, which is 2.1.0 at this time. I don't understand why it works for you, not for me...

Comment: Have you tried removing the double quotes and the htmlentities function?

Like this:
$this->email->to('t@t.com');

Comment: I remove the double quote, it doesn't work. So, I removed the htmlentities, it doesn't work.                                                 To me more precise, I have the "not sent" message but before to have it, i have the error message like above.

Comment: What happens when you send an email to a valid and existent address? Do you get an error too, or is it sent?
If it's not working maybe it's a server error in which case you should contact your administrator. Take a look at apache's error logs (if you can)

Comment: It works perfect when I send to a valid email address.                      I don't see anything in the apache log... I thought about the server but as it works for a valid email address, I don't think I will be that

Comment: I tried on testprod server and it returns me "sent". No error and send() function returns me always true, even if the mail is not good.      I think it's my local mail server which replies an error... but what about the prod server if send() function replies always true ? How can I know when the email is inexistent ?

Comment: it's a mail server problem. I just test with php mail command, and it replies the same error message with the 550 error smtp.

Comment: Are you usin WAMP or XAMP? I think you'll have to reinstall. Good luck

Comment: Yes, i am using xamp. You think the problem comes from it ? Did you have the problem ? I will try it, why not.

Comment: Just try with the most recent version, maybe it'll solve the problem. I tested it in one of my servers, so idk. Good luck